# Passing scanner to method

Tags: java, class, methods

Can anybody tell me why the date prints `0/0/0`?
What part of the code is missing so the values input using Scanner are passed into the method `DisplayDate` and printed on the screen?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter day:");
    int day = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter month:");
    int month = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter year:");
    int year = scanner.nextInt();

    Date d = new Date(day,month,year);
    d.DisplayDate();

}

}

class Date {

private int day;
private int month;
private int year;


public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

public void setDay(int day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public int getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(int month) {
    this.month = month;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}


public void DisplayDate() {
    System.out.println(getDay() + "/" + getMonth() + "/" + getYear());
}

}
```

Comment: Why did you write your own `Date` class? Also, `DisplayDate()`? Why not `toString()`? And, what does your question have to do with your headline? You aren't passing your `Scanner` to any function... did you want to?

Comment: @user3752579 U gonna go long way...as you are answered by gods of coders.... :)

Comment: No need to pass Scanner to any function. Just to print out the values inserted.

Answer (score 6):

You are not saving your day, month and year. You should do it in the constructor:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}
```

Comment: @Bartdude Wait... LOL!

Comment: On the other hand, now that he completed his answer, the few seconds delay he had in the beginning can be forgot :-) But your answer is still the correct one and should be the one that gets validated even if Jon's answer is as usual full of good advices

Answer (score 6):

This is the problem:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
}
```

Your constructor completely ignores its parameters, leaving your fields with their default values. For `int` fields, that's 0.

Instead, it should save the values, e.g.

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}
```

or perhaps call your properties:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    setDay(day);
    setMonth(month);
    setYear(year);
}
```

I'd also *strongly* recommend that:

1. You make the type immutable (remove the setters, make the class final, make the fields final)
2. You try to think "year month day" rather than "day month year" (so reorder the parameters)
3. You validate the parameters
4. You follow Java naming conventions (change `DisplayDate` to `displayDate`, or separate the concern of formatting from writing to the console, by just overriding `toString` instead)
5. You avoid creating your own date type entirely, and instead use the types in java.time (if you're on Java 8) or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) otherwise.

Comment: hey buddy what u eat for making brain like this... :)

Comment: I knew you would come with such a complete answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations Jon. I m new to programming and a comment like yours helps heaps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor does nothing:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
}
```

it accepts the appropriate values, but doesn't do anything with them. Notice how `DisplayDate` calls your getter methods: `getDay()`, `getMonth()`, and `getYear()`? The values returned by those getters are the instance variables defined at the top of your class: `day`, `month`, and `year` respectively. Since these values were never initialized with the proper values, they default to 0.

A more sensible constructor would be:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
   this.day   = day; 
   this.month = month;
   this.year  = year;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your contructor to:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.day=day;
    this.month=month;
    this.year=year;
}
```

The problem is that you never set the variables you are requesting later!

Answer (score 0):

Because your Constructor of the Date class is empty!

Change it to the following and it will work:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your Date class is empty, so the values are not set when you create a new Date object.